# Angular 4 out of box app URL fails to run in Samsung Galaxy S5 browser

Tags: android, angular, mobile

I have angular cli v1.0.2 (& node 7.9.0) installed in my Windows 7 laptop. Successful in creating out of the box Angular 4 project and able to run in FF browser. I could also build & deploy this app in a public cloud and successful in running this URL from my laptop FF browser. However if I access this URL thru moblie phone, browser (display gets stuck in the index.html page) displaying "Loading...". Not sure whether Angular 4 app, by default would be able run in a mobile browser OR do we need any special tasks for mobile. BTW, I have Samsung Galaxy S5. Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it on my own. Here is what I did. Earlier I was using the "Google" app. It failed. Later if I use the FireFox or Chrome apps that is already part of the Samsung list of apps, it worked. Looks like some limitations thru Google app. Either way I am happy, since I was worried earlier on whether my Angular app is broke for mobile or what. I am glad it is good and working. Thanks to all for your contributions in Stack Overflow.